# How to set a class to markdown **bold** style with markdown-it?

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown-it

I'm using `@nuxtjs/markdownit` Nuxt module, how can I add a class to **bold** style ? For instance, use Boostrap's `primary` class to the word `Hello` in `**Hello** World!`, to have it in blue.

```
<template>
  <v-col>
    <div v-html="$md.render(foo)"></div>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: '**Hello** World!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using this config in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
markdownit: {
  injected: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: '<span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">**Hello**</span> World!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```